# Rally Custom Data Store Issue

Tags: rally

I am trying to create a custom rally data store and pass it to rally grid. But I am getting the following error: "Uncaught Error: Cannot configure store with no models defined". But I did specify the model of the custom store.

Uncaught Error: Cannot configure store with no models defined

```
    var retrievedRecords = myStore.getRecords();

    var defectRecords = [];

    Ext.Array.each(retrievedRecords, function(record) {
        //Perform custom actions with the data here
        //Calculations, etc.
        defectRecords.push({
            FormattedID: record.get('FormattedID'),
            Name: record.get('Name'),
            State: record.get('State'),
            Release: record.get('Release'),
            FixedInBuild: record.get('FixedInBuild'),
            SubmittedBy: record.get('SubmittedBy'),
            Owner: record.get('Owner'),
            CreationDate: record.get('CreationDate'),
            ReleaseNote: record.get('ReleaseNote')
        });
    });

    this.newStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                        data: defectRecords,
                        model: 'Defect',
                        autoSync:true,
                        listeners: {
                            load: this._newStoreOnLoad(),
                            scope: this
                        },
                        autoLoad: true
                    });
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `model` on a custom store. Custom store needs `data` that is stitched together - maybe even from different sources, that's why you are using a custom store, and not wsapi store to represent a modified or eclectic data. See [this example](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-defects-of-current-sprint-with-tasks) or [another example](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/custom-data) where the following is enough to instantiate a custom store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: myCustomData
            });
```

However, before a custom data is stitched together from Rally data, that initial Rally data has to be stored in your code in [Rally.data.wsapi.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.Store) or [Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store). Those stores require `model`. Check your code to see if a Rally store is present, and if it is, if it has `model`, because chances are the error comes from that part of your code.